# How to replace the NULL value of the last row of a column with 'Grand total' while retaining 'Total' replacing NULL value in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

Below is the table created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    Id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Gender VARCHAR(50),
    Salary INTEGER,
    Country VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Mark', 'Male', 5000, 'USA')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('John', 'Male', 4500, 'India')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Pam', 'Female', 5500, 'USA')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Sara', 'Female', 4000, 'India')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Todd', 'Male', 3500, 'India')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Mary', 'Female', 5000, 'UK')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Ben', 'Male', 6500, 'UK')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Elizabeth', 'Female', 7000, 'USA')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Tom', 'Male', 5500, 'UK')
INSERT INTO Employees (Name, Gender, Salary, Country)
VALUES ('Ron', 'Male', 5000, 'USA')

SELECT * FROM Employees
```

Now I ran the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(Country, '') AS [Country],
    COALESCE(Gender, 'Total') AS [Gender],
    SUM(Salary) AS [Total Salary]
FROM
    Employees 
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(Country, Gender)
```

When you look at the query result, the last row of the Gender column has the value 'Total' in it.

I want to replace 'Total' with 'Grand Total' only in the last row of Gender column while keeping 'Total' text in the other rows of Gender column.

Is there any possibility to achieve that ?

If so, then what is the simplest possible way to achieve it ?

Comment: SQL results don't have order, by default.  You can put an ORDER BY on your query to put the nulls wherever you want in the presentation order, but you'd need to specify the ORDER you want.  NULLs sort low in SQL Server collations, so you might need to do something like ORDER BY a computed value before country, gender, to put the nulls last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GROUPING_ID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for it:

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(Country,'') AS [Country],
   CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(Country)=1 THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE COALESCE(Gender,'Total') END as [Gender],
   SUM(Salary) AS [Total Salary]
FROM Employees 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Country,Gender)
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d82bd77888f4f7931dce5b5b005ecd4)

EDIT: In the comment of the question is noted that the order of the result should be specified, to make sure it is correct.

This query can be ordered like this, to make sure totals are below the details.

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(Country,'') AS [Country],
   CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(Country)=1 THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE COALESCE(Gender,'Total') END as [Gender],
   SUM(Salary) AS [Total Salary],
   GROUPING_ID(Country),
   GROUPING_ID(Gender)
FROM Employees 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Country,Gender)
ORDER BY COALESCE(Country,'ZZZ'),GROUPING_ID(Country),
         Gender,GROUPING_ID(Gender)
```

Comment: With this solution It is also possible to put `Total India` and so on... in the Gender columns if that is desired

Comment: @Luuk it worked perfectly.
Just one question
 
What does 1 mean  (inside the CASE statement) ?
and what is the purpose of GROUPING_ID ?

Comment: @pro_data: It is explained on the link in my answer.  I never used another value than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

One other easy way would be to just to concatenate the country name using *isnull* which is preferable in Sql server with just two values, such as:

```
select 
  isnull(Country,'') Country, 
  isnull(Gender, Concat(IsNull(Country, 'Grand'), ' Total')) Gender,
    Sum(Salary) [Total Salary]
from Employees 
group by rollup(Country,Gender);
```

Comment: Problem is what happens if there is a `NULL` grouping as well as the rollup grouping. This is why it's normally better to use `GROUPING_ID`